# Joomla Gnu licensing clarification

Tags: php, joomla, gnu

I am trying to create a new Open Source CMS. Is it legally alright if I use the Joomla admin theme and other front end themes for my CMS? The new CMS code will be free for all to modify, view etc.

I am just trying to understand the way GNU licensing works. No offense to this great CMS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  questions about licensing issues are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a new cms. Using code from Joomla?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056698/creating-a-new-cms-using-code-from-joomla)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it OK to fork Joomla templates? Of course, if they are released under [GPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) then providing your modifications are released under the same license, and existing copyrights are left intact / properly attributed, then you are good to go.

Each Joomla template, both front and back-end is released under it's own license anyway, so you'd need to check the license on each and I'd suggest as a courtesy at least contacting the author / copyright holder.